# launch fargate task with dynamic policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I would like to launch an ECS fargate TASK while granting dynamic permissions on the container. More specifically, I want the container to be able to access a single file in s3, which I only know about at runtime.

I tried to use `sts:GetFederationToken` to achieve the following (spoiler, it doesn't work):

[image]

- lambda gets called with some `fileName`
- lambda calls `GetFederationToken` with policy restriction on the specific s3 file
- Obtain tokens and pass them to the container (using container overrides)

Unfortunately, this does not work and I'm stuck with the following error:

> AccessDenied: Cannot call GetFederationToken with session credentials

From what I now understand, it appears that lambda is already using a temp session, and can therefore not call `sts:GetFederationToken`.

Is there any way to achieve what I'm trying to do here ? To recap, I would like a lambda to launch a fargate task that has access rights on a specific s3 file. I cannot know the s3 file in advance (*i.e.* I cannot create a proper policy beforehand)

**EDIT**

To clarify things a bit more:

- I can NOT know the file name before the lambda is called. The file name depends on user parameters, and is sent to the lambda by the user, at runtime
- Multiple containers will run at the same time, and no container should have permission to see anything else than its own legit file (*i.e.* containers cannot be trusted)

Comment: Can't your lambda function copy the object to other s3 location with pre-defined name, or maybe into some common prefix? Then your ecs tasks can have only one only permissions to access the copy?

Comment: Thing is, I don't want two jobs to be able to see each otther's files, so this won't work neither

Answer (score 3):

Given you only know the file beforehand, you need to pass the file name to the task at runtime - perhaps the cleanest way is to use 'ContainerOverides/Environment' to set a variable when calling the 'run_task' api.

You don't need to create a new task definition but you do need to do ***something***.

There are a finite amount of realistic options, and you have to make a trade off.

Assuming the container task knows the file to read via it's environment, and assuming the file is in a bucket in the same account as the container and access is to be via an AWS sdk:

- the task role can have s3:GetObject on a wildcard but the s3 bucket policy needs to grant access to the principal ( the task role )
- if there is no access granted via a bucket policy, then the task role needs to have, or assume a role that has, specific access to the file via an identity policy.

If the s3 object is in a different account, both the bucket policy needs to give access to the principal and the task role need to give access to the object.

That's just how IAM works so you have to make some change to either the IAM policy on the ECS Task Role or the S3 Bucket policy before running the task.

GetFederationToken is not the right solution here-either you do the above or go down the road of using a pre signed url for the s3 object and having it access it over http - but i'm assuming an sdk is required

TLDR: I'd be looking to pass the file to read as an environment var and update the policy of the ecs task role though note that the task would retain access until the policy was amended unless the policy had a condition with an aws:CurrentTime clause

Comment: You make a very good point with presigned URL. I'm a little worried that the url will expire too soon though. The doc says a presigned URL expires when the token of its creator expires. In the case of a lambda invocation, I'm not quite sure how long this would be ?

As to changing policy, the thing is I don't want two different jobs to have access rights on each other's data so this won't do it neither

Answer (score 0):

Can you create some sort of wildcard permission for the S3 file?
If security is #1 priority on the files you can go a bit more advanced:

With the lambda you can create a custom policy (that allows access to that object in S3) and taskdefinition. Assign the taskpolicy to the taskdefinition and deploy the taskdefinition in the ECS service. Should all be possible with SDK.

Comment: Won't do: I don't want the container to be able to access any other file so no wildcard.
Also, creating resources (task definitions) at each run doesn't look good to me

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is the following, although I'm not sure it's very standard:

- create a "broker" AWS user with wildcard permissions on s3 (and only that)
- create static keys for the user, and store them in `secrets manager`
- At runtime, lambda can read "broker's creds" and call `federate identity` to create a temporary session with restricted access on a specific s3 file
- the temporary creds can be sent to the container instance using environment variables

[image]

It's basically the same approach than in the question, but this time we use static credentials rather than the lambda's assumed role to create the session.

I can tell for sure that it works, but I'm not quite sure it's the best way to do it.

Comment: This issue has sort of intrigued me. Environment vars are not secure and passing creds that way is really to be avoided, in my opinion - how quickly does the container need to come up? Can you wait a minute ?